# keycloak : importing users from multiple user federations (ldap)

Tags: jakarta-ee, keycloak, openid-connect

I have a Jakarta web application with two IdentityStores plugged in two differents LDAP servers. Some persons are registered in both LDAP servers with the same username but with different email adresses. It works well thanks to the IdentityStores different priorities.

Now I'm trying to use Keycloak to enable SSO for example. So I created a realm with two User Federations. Problem : the users present in both LDAP servers are not imported, only the first imported User Federation wins. When I import the second User Federation, the users already in Keycloak are not imported twice, although the emails are different.

So what shall I do to use Keycloak with this two LDAP servers ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly  by "the users present in both LDAP servers"? Which attributes are the same?

Comment: They have the same "sAMAccountName" in both LDAP servers. So they end up with the same username in Keycloak.

Comment: And how about using a different attribute for "userName"? e.g. userPrincipalName or objectGUID.